# Add basic authentication of WordPress on any external PHP file?

Tags: api, authentication

I have a file named `upload.php` that is an API which does the job of uploading images to the server. I want that file to have a basic authentication of WordPress, so that while accessing that php from postman it asks a basic authentication details of wp user? Please help me to reach there. Thank You.

Comment: WordPress doesn't use basic authentication. If you want code running in WordPress with Basic Auth you need to re-implement your upload.php file as a [custom REST API endpoint](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/) combined with the [Basic Auth plugin](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth).